# openstack installation on vmware

Tags: cloud, virtual-machine, openstack, vmware-workstation

I've successfully installed [OpenStack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStack) on a virtual machine Ubuntu 14 desktop on vmware workstation 
and there are 2 different installation methods; cloning the repository or using

```
sudo apt-get install openstack
```

what's the difference between the two methods? could that be something to do with devstack and openstack?

also how can i make other VM's access the horizon dashboard.

finally where can i go from here if I want to build a cloud and control it?

P.S I'm not sure if this quistion belongs to Stackoverflow or ServerFault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every distribution has its repositories which keep the packages that it uses. For example, Ubuntu is based on deb and its package manager is dpkg. So installing something through the package manager you get what the community has tested and packaged for a specific release. In the other hand cloning the repository you get software with the latest commits and you have to install it manual.

> how can i make other VM's access the horizon dashboard
>   Usually you have to setup a floating ips and ext-ips to your nodes to be accessable.
>   you can check your floating ips and ext with

```
neutron floatingips-list

neutron ext-list
```

> where can i go from here if I want to build a cloud and control it?
>   there are many guides and tutorial. You can use your terminal or a browser.

Comment: thnx for your explanation ... appreciated